# Read a file and modify it

Tags: regex, perl, aix

I'm trying to process a stream of data.

First I cat a text file to my script.

The text file goes like this :

```
pierwsza linia  koniec
druga linia lorem1 koniec lorem1 lorem1
trzecia linia lorem1 koniec lorem1
czwarta linia lorem1 koniec
piata liniakoniec
szosta linia lorem1 koniec
```

What I want to achieve is a file with all lines but with just the first occurrence of `lorem1`.

so the expected result should be like this

```
pierwsza linia  koniec
druga linia lorem1 koniec
trzecia linia koniec
czwarta linia koniec
piata liniakoniec
szosta linia koniec
```

My script goes like this

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -pi

use strict;

my $line = $_;
my $loremcn;

while ( $line = <> ) {

    #if ( $line =~ m/lorem1/ )

    foreach ( $line =~ m/lorem1/gi ) {

        $loremcn++;

        if ( $loremcn >= 2 ) {
            $line =~ s/lorem1//gi;
        }

        print "$loremcn\n";
        print $line;

        chomp $line;
    }
}
```

However the result is just one, first line (because of the `-pi` at the beginning of the script) of text.

The script properly counts occurrences of `lorem1` (7) but because of the `/g` option it deletes all `lorem1` occurrences (it doesn't leave the first alone).

Lastly, how at the end print the whole corrected text to the screen?

#### Update

I wrote this important comment on one of the answers:

> In RL I cannot do this Your way. This whole excercise is to find a way on how to do this with streamed data. In true scenario the whole data is not from opened text, but it's a spool data streamed to printer from SAP. And that data needs to be corrected on the way to the printer

Comment: but you are telling it to delete each occurrence of it if the count is more than 1.

Comment: and what is the purpose of `chomp` at the end of the script, when you printed `$line` already?

Comment: yes I just editied the line  from 
    $line =~s/lorem1//gi; 
to 
    $line =~s/lorem1//;

the chomp is just a leftover I forgot to delete ;) 
 it doesn't do anything. 

What I'm struggling with, is how to at the end either print the whole editied text or save it to file (that I could achieve with printing and simple > in a command line bu first I need to print it somehow)

and I don't understand why at the end it prints the first line ?

Comment: I'm unclear what it is that you want. You seem to want all occurrences of `lorem1` *after the first* removed from the document. Is that right? But your code does something different: It removes all instances or `lorem1` from each line where it appears twice or more. Which is correct?

Comment: Hi
I want to delete all occurences of lorem1 after the first occurence from the document, and at the end print on the screen the whole edited text.

Comment: If you need a one line way to perform this, you can simply do: `perl -pe s/lorem1.*?\Klorem1.*// yourfile.txt > new_file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

# lorem counter
my $loremcn = 0;
# loop over the input file
while (my $line = <> ) {
    # if line contains lorem1 but not alorem1 or lorem12
    if ($line =~ /\blorem1\b/i) {
        # not the first time. counter > 0
        if ($loremcn) {
            # remove all lorem1 and optional leading horizontal spaces
            $line =~ s/\h*\blorem1\b//gi;   # comment for syntax color /
        # first time lorem1 is encountered (counter == 0)
        } else {
            # remove all lorem1 but the first
        while ($line =~ s/
                            (\blorem1\b.*?)     # first lorem1 in the line followed by 0 or more anycharacter
                            \blorem1\b          # subsequent lorem1
                            /$1/gix             # replace with the first group (i.e. the first lorem1
            ) { 1;}
        }
        # incement counter
        $loremcn++;
    }
    # print the modified line
    print $line;
}
```

**Output:**

```
pierwsza linia  koniec
druga linia lorem1 koniec  
trzecia linia koniec
czwarta linia koniec
piata liniakoniec
szosta linia koniec
```

**Usage:**

```
perl test.pl inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: I tried Your code but it resulted with :i'm executing this on aix if this will help  

    
pierwsza linia  koniec  
druga linia lorem1 koniec lorem1 lorem1  
trzecia linia  koniec  
czwarta linia  koniec  
piata liniakoniec  
szosta linia  koniec

Comment: @Deneth: Really? That's strange, I've just tested it and it works. What is your perl version?

Comment: 5.8.2 (can't upgrade it)

Comment: @Deneth: Too bad :( I think `\K` and/or `\G` is not recognize.

Comment: @Deneth: See my edit, this should work  with perl 5.8.2

Comment: @Deneth: It is essential to provide information like the operating system you are using and the version of Perl that you have. Unless you specify otherwise, people will assume that you are running Linux of some sort and a version of Perl that is around v5.14 (which is already four years old) or better. If you are using Windows or an Apple system prior to Mac OS X, or a particularly old version of Perl then you *must* say so.

Comment: You can simply do: `perl -pe s/lorem1.*?\Klorem1.*// yourfile.txt>new_file.txt`

Comment: @Onyambu: That was (close) my first solution. Version 5.8.2 doesn't recognize `\K`

Comment: @Toto i did give the solution below. Why cant it work eith \K?.. am using 5.3.25 and it allows the usage of \K. Anyway there is an option which does not use  \Kin my answer below

Comment: @Onyambu: Have a look at my answer before editing. I've used `\K` and `\G`, It didn't work with 5.8.2, I don't know if it was because of `\G` or `\K`.

Comment: @Toto, I have not edited my answer. I did look at your answer. It has a double loop, meaning a higher complexity, and I was trying to avoid that. That's why I wrote a different answer which does not ue `\K` or `\G`

Answer (score 1):

One liner using `perl`:

You can keep everything until the first lorem then delete all the lorems after this ie

```
 $perl -pe "undef $/;s/^.*?\blorem1\K|\blorem1//g" lorem.txt
```

- `\b` -used to determine the boundary.
- `.*?`- non-greedy match. matches everything to the second `lorem`
- `\K` - discard any previously consumed characters. Thus deleting from the second lorem to the end

output

```
pierwsza linia  koniec
druga linia lorem1 koniec
trzecia linia  koniec
czwarta linia  koniec
piata liniakoniec
szosta linia  koniec
```

Now if you want to save this in another file, you can do:

```
perl -pe "undef $/;s/^.*?\blorem1\K|\blorem1//g" lorem.txt > new_file.txt
```

If your version of `perl` does not support `\K`, you can use:

```
 perl -pe "undef $/;s/(^.*?\blorem1)|\blorem1/$1/g" lorem.txt
```

Comment: Did you miss the comments where OP said he was stuck on perl 5.8 and that he wanted *all* occurrences of the word after the first one removed, not all but the first on each line? Compare his desired output to what that produces...

Comment: @Shawn, I hope now this meets the requirements

Comment: Look up what version of perl `\K` was introduced in.

Comment: @Shawn I really cant tell when, but if that is a problem, one can just do `s/(^.*?\blorem1)|\blorem1/$1/g` which will still work. There are a ton of regular expressions to be used

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just this?

```
my $seen;
while (<>) {
  s/\blorem1\b//g if $seen;
  $seen = 1 if /\blorem1\b/;
  print;
}
```

**Update:** Ok, it's a little more complicated than I originally thought. But this seems to do what you wanted:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $seen;

while (<>) {
  if ($seen) {
    s/\blorem1\b//g;
  } else {
    1 while s/(?<=\blorem1\b)(.*)\blorem1\b/$1/g;
    $seen = 1 if /\blorem1\b/;
  }
  print;
}
```

Comment: This will not remove the second and third lorem1 in line 2

Answer (score -1):

Running your code with `B::Deparse` like this

```
perl -MO=Deparse xx.pl
```

gives this result

```
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }   # From -i

LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {


    use strict;
    my $line = $_;
    my $loremcn;
    while (defined($line = readline ARGV)) {
        foreach $_ ($line =~ /lorem1/gi) {
            ++$loremcn;
            if ($loremcn >= 2) {
                $line =~ s/lorem1//gi;
            }
            print "$loremcn\n";
            print $line;
            chomp $line;
        }
    }


}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

So you see that you have *two* `while` loops in your code: you shouldn't mix up command-line options with a program file, as the result may be non-obvious

Here's a way to do what I *think* you want. It uses your global counter `$loremcn` together with an *expression* global substitution to replace `lorem1` with nothing after the first instance

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

@ARGV = 'file1.txt';

my $loremcn = 0;

while ( <> ) {

    s{(\blorem1\b[ \t]*)}{ $loremcn++ ? '' : $1 }ge;

    print;
}
```

#### output

```
pierwsza linia  koniec
druga linia lorem1 koniec 
trzecia linia koniec 
czwarta linia koniec
piata liniakoniec
szosta linia koniec
```

Comment: thank You but in RL I cannot do this Your way. This whole excercise is to find a way on how to do this with streamed data.  In true scenario the whole data is not from opened text, but it's a spool data streamed to printer from SAP.  And that data needs to be corrected on the way to the printer :)

Comment: @Deneth: Then you have misrepresented the problem in your question: note that you wrote *"First I cat a text file to my script"*, which is ***not*** streamed data. In future, please provide all the information that is necessary to reproduce your problem. You should do your best to avoid wasting our time, and it is very important that you read [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please apply the advice there to any future questions.